# Opening an excel file with opn while another excel file is open, will execute code immediately without waiting

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using a library called [opn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn). This makes it easier to spawn a child process to open a file in the main process of electron. I could use shell but I need to be able to detect when the file is closed which shell API doesn't provide.

Whenever I open an excel file and there are no other excel files opened, it will work fine and it will wait until I close the file before it resolve the promise. However, if there are other excel files open then it won't wait for the file to be closed and it will resolve the promise immediately.

I did some digging in the source code of the library and the command used to open the file is this for windows: `start "" /wait name_of_file` where name_of_file is a place holder for the file. The actual command the library executes is different but this one is enough for my use case. I ran into the same problem even when doing it manually without using the library. Maybe I should post this under super user instead of stackoverflow.

Here is the code that opens the file, wait for the file then executes callback.

```
opn(file, { app: 'EXCEL', wait: true }).then(() => {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  papa.parse(stream, {
    delimiter: ',',
    complete: (results) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('uploadNewIndexFileRen', key,
        results.data);
    },
    error: (err) => {
      throw err;
    }
  });
}).catch((error) => { throw error; });
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a quick nodejs [repo](https://github.com/hyalkaf/nodejs-opening-multiple-excel-file-problem-opn). All you need to do is clone/fork to check the problem or make a pull request then do npm install to download needed packages. To reproduce the exact problem that I have you might need to be in the following software versions:

- Window 10
- npm 5.5.1
- node v8.9.1
- excel 2013
- opn 5.2.0 as seen in package.json

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the way Excel handles files. I'm guessing Excel handles files with a single process so subsequent opening of files simply signals to the existing process that another files needs opening before closing.

You may be able to force Excel to open a new instance for each file by following [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default).

Apparently using the `/x` command line switch will also start a new process:

```
excel.exe /x
```

Comment: Yeah, Excel seems to spawn a single process for all the files. Is there a workaround to get it to detect a certain file only?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I did `start /wait name_of_file excel.exe /x`. Still exits immediately

Comment: I imagine you'll have to locate `excel.exe` in the file system and call it like in the example: `c:\path\to\excel.exe /x name_of_file.xls`

Comment: The thing is, excel 2013 and up lanuchs a new instance by default. However all instances are under the same process. `/x` seems to launch a new instance not a new process

Comment: Once they're open in separate windows you could use the [winctl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winctl) library to keep track of windows?